# click on li list with phantomJS 2.2

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

So I have created an automated test in c# that needs to click a link in a list, the function works when i run the test with chrome driver, but with PhantomJS 2.2 nothing is happening.

Im have tried the custom `element.click();` but also
JavaScriptExecutor

```
 var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)browser.Driver;
 js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Another thing i tried was to wait for the element and click, 
If I wait for the element with the wait function,

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0,  seconds));
  wait.Until((d) => element.Displayed);
```

the test waits for the element, then tries to click the list, but of course nothing is triggered.

But if i use `element.ElementToBeClickable` it wats until timeout.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
        }
```

Any suggestions? saw that this was a bug in an older version, cant find anything for this one though

This is the list,

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <a>
  </a>
 </li>
  <li>
  <a>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a>
  </a>
 </li>
<li>
 <a>
 </a>
</li>
</ul>
```